# Can I use `regular polygon` wthout using `\node`?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For instance, I can execute this command:

```
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=black,opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (2cm);
```

But I want something for regular polygons as well, something like this:

```
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=black,opacity=0.3] (0,0) regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6 (2cm);
```

Is such a command available, or should I first write `\newcommand` and define a script to do this?

Comment: The first command draws and fills a circle, which is nothing else than a circle. Once it is drawn you cannot do anything else with it.  `Nodes` are something more than lines and points. They are the only way to write text on our figures, but they are also special objects which can be named and used as references to add other elements. You don't need a `\newcommand`, just `\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw=black, fill=blue, opacity=0.3, minimum size=2cm] at (0,0) {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I present two solutions, both have advantages and disadvantages :

- the first one use `pics` and `node`, so you have to specify the actions (fill, draw...) separately from the path. For example you can use `pic[draw]{poly=5:1cm}` to draw a pentagon with **inner radius** of 1cm.
- the second one use `insert path` and is more close to `circle` in a way that it insert simply the path corresponding to the polygon, and so use the path's actions. For example you can use `[poly=5:1cm]` to insert a pentagon with **outer radius** of 1cm.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % <- for regular polygon nodes
\tikzset{
  pics/poly/.style args={#1:#2}{
    code = {
      \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides={#1}, pic actions,
        outer sep=0pt,inner sep={#2}] at (0,0){};
    }
  },
  poly/.style args={#1:#2}{
    insert path={
      +(0:#2) foreach ~ in {1,...,#1}{ -- +(~*360/#1:#2)} +(0,0)
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (1,1)
      [poly=7:1cm]
      -- (4,1)
      pic[fill=red, opacity=.5]{poly=7:1cm}
      -- (2,2)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]